# Alter tkinter canvas objects after drawing

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to create a 2D map made up of green and black squares in tkinter. Each square has a small text.

```
canvasObjects = {}
for i, row in enumerate(self.map):
            for j, cell in enumerate(row):
                color = "black" if cell else "green"
                canvasObject[(i,j)] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                    r * i, r * j, r * (i + 1), r * (j + 1), outline=color, fill=color)
                canvasObject[(i,j, "text")] = self.land[(i, j)] = self.canvas.create_text(
                    r * i, r * j, anchor=NE, fill="white", text="1", tag=str((i, j)))
```

How can I later on in the code alter the attributes of the objects? For instance how can I change the color of a square or change the text for one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not really work with your code in particular because it was only a snippet of a much larger thing.  However, this should demonstrate how to do what you want.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,70,70, outline="blue", fill="red")
def switch():
    # Use the itemconfig method of a Canvas to alter specific items
    canvas.itemconfig(rect, outline="green", fill="blue")
Button(root, text="switch", command=switch).pack()
root.mainloop()
```